# Sencha Touch JW Player not playing with multiple overlays

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, jwplayer

In My Sencha touch 2.0 app I am having an issue with a JW javascript video player not playing when there are two overlays up at the same time and I wanted to see if anyone could better elaborate on what is going wrong or what may be causing it so I can try and look around and try to figure out what is going on (i am new to sencha and javascript). I have the project loaded up at http://www.cox7.com/sean even tho it will only be run on an iPad.

Try the steps below to better see what I am talking about and also note that a lot of the jwplayer events are being logged in the javascript console so you can see whats going on......

1) click on any of the panels on the main page which will open a overlay with the video title description and a javascript video player. You will see that you can play the video.

2) do a search for "stem" in the search bar (top right corner of the main screen) this will then display a pannel with the search results.

3) click on any of the search results which will then open that same video player pannel but this time you will not be able to click the play button. It's almost like the pannel is not the top most element but I can still scroll and the onTouchStart event fires but the video never starts.

Anyone know what might be causing this? any help is much appreciated.

Here is my controller setup for the search result overlay....

```
showStreamSearchPopup: function showStreamPopup(list, index, node, record) {
            //alert(record.get('title'));
                        //var record = getData().getStore().getAt(index);
                            StreamVideoSearchPlayerOverlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                modal: true,
                                hideOnMaskTap: true,
                                showAnimation: {
                                    type: 'popIn',
                                    duration: 200,
                                    easing: 'ease-out'
                                },
                                hideAnimation: {
                                    type: 'popOut',
                                    duration: 200,
                                    easing: 'ease-out'
                                },
                                centered: true,
                                width: '78%',
                                height: '68%',
                                styleHtmlContent: true,
                                listeners: {
                                    painted: function() {
                                        console.log('StreamVideoSearchPlayerOverlay painted');
                                   },
                                   activeitemchange :function() {
                                        console.log('StreamVideoSearchPlayerOverlay activeitemchange');
                                   }
                                },
                                items: [{
                                style: 'padding:1em;',
                                html:[  "<div class=\"postTitle\">",record.get('title'),"</div><div class=\"postDate\">Added on ",
                                    record.get('date'),"</div><div class=\"postDesc\">",record.get('content'),"</div>"      
                                ].join("") 
                    },


                    {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'card',
                    cls: 'videoPlayeriPad',
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'jwplayer',
                        playerOptions: {
                            file: record.get('ipadvideo'),
                            image: record.get('poster'),
                            width: 500, 
                            height: 281,
                            plugins: {
                             'gapro-1': { accountid: 'UA-23363754-1', idstring: '||title||' }
                            },
                            skin: 'http://www.cox7.com/wp-content/mediaplayer/skins/beelden/beelden/glow.xml',

                        }
                    }]
                    }

                    ],
                                scrollable: true
                            }

                            );




                    StreamVideoSearchPlayerOverlay.show();
                    StreamVideoSearchPlayerOverlay.setActiveItem(2);
                    },
```

And here is my controller setup for the normal home screen asset overlay...

```
showStreamPopup: function showStreamPopup(list, index, node, record) {

                        //alert(record.get('title'));
                        //var record = getData().getStore().getAt(index);

                            StreamVideoPlayerOverlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                modal: true,
                                hideOnMaskTap: true,
                                showAnimation: {
                                    type: 'popIn',
                                    duration: 200,
                                    easing: 'ease-out'
                                },
                                hideAnimation: {
                                    type: 'popOut',
                                    duration: 200,
                                    easing: 'ease-out'
                                },
                                centered: true,
                                width: '78%',
                                height: '68%',
                                styleHtmlContent: true,
                                listeners: {
                                    painted: function() {
                                        console.log('StreamVideoPlayerOverlay painted');
                                   },
                                   activeitemchange :function() {
                                        console.log('StreamVideoPlayerOverlay activeitemchange');
                                   }
                                },
                                items: [{
                                style: 'padding:1em;',
                            html:[  "<div class=\"postTitle\">",record.get('title'),"</div><div class=\"postDate\">Added on ",
                                    record.get('date'),"</div><div class=\"postDesc\">",record.get('content'),"</div>"
                                ].join("") 
                    },

                    {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'card',
                    cls: 'videoPlayeriPad',
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'jwplayer',
                        playerOptions: {
                            file: record.get('ipadvideo'),
                            image: record.get('poster'),
                            width: 500, 
                            height: 281,
                            plugins: {
                             'gapro-1': { accountid: 'UA-23363754-1', idstring: '||title||' }
                            },
                            skin: 'http://www.cox7.com/wp-content/mediaplayer/skins/beelden/beelden/glow.xml',

                        }
                    }]
                    }
                    ],
                                scrollable: true
                            }

                            );


                    StreamVideoPlayerOverlay.setActiveItem(2);
                    StreamVideoPlayerOverlay.show();
                    }
```